# Rationality of higher dimensional du Val singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, resolution-of-singularities

I am interested in the isolated singularity defined over $\mathbb{C}$ by
$$
x_1^2+\cdots + x_n^2+x_{n+1}^k=0,
$$
where $n>2$ and $k>2$.

I would like to know whether this singularity is rational, as in the surface case. Any reference is welcome.

Comment: These are discussed in the book of Arnold, Gusein-Zade and Varchenko.  e.g the Milnor number is k-1.  perhaps pages 121, 242, vol. 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **yes**.

In the sequel, I will refer to S. Ishii's book *[Introduction to Singularities](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9784431550808)* ([Is]). We have the following

> **Proposition.** An $n$-dimensional isolated $1$-Gorenstein singularity $(X, \, x)$ is rational if and only if $\kappa_{\delta}(X, \, x) = - \infty.$

For a discussion, see [Is, Section 8.4]; the invariant $\kappa_{\delta}$ is introduced in [Is, Section 6.3].

Now, given a hypersurface singularity of the form $(\{f=0\}, \, 0)$, where $$f=x_1^{a_1}+ \cdots +x_{n+1}^{a_{n+1}},$$
the above condition on  $\kappa_{\delta}$ can be translated as follows: $$\kappa_{\delta}(X, \, x) = - \infty \iff \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{a_i} >1,$$ see again [Is, Section 8.4]. From this, it follows immediately what you want.

Note that this also implies that your singularity is canonical, since for a $1$-Gorenstein normal singularity being canonical and being rational are equivalent conditions, see [Is, Corollary 6.2.15].